# Custom notification with difference between current time

Tags: android

I have custom notification with textview.

This notification have a custom content:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_context, "id")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smoke_icon)
            .setContent(contentView)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setOngoing(prefManager.getPrefNotify());
```

In this custom content, I have textview.
In this textview I can put text:

```
String currentHour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(hour);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.id_hours, currentHour);
```

Inside this textview I want to put the difference from current time and when the notification arrived, like whatsapp or facebook notification "2min, 10min, 1day" etc..

For example, If I recieve notification 10mins ago, I can see 10min..

How can I create this?

Comment: What do you mean by `current time` and `notification arrived`? Please elaborate on the specific time window that you need

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: The behavior that you're describing (Like whatsapp or facebook)  is handled by default on Android. Any notification that is received will be marked with timestamp on when it was received. Try, for example, sending your notification and check how it looks when it arrives. You will the timestamp on the right side of it indicating when you received it.

Comment: Yes, I know that using .setWhen , I can see the difference by default. But I have custom notification with custom container, I can't use setWhen